# How do I reselect/filter elements when I already have a jquery object?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, selector

```
function initItems($items, current, count) {
    $items.removeClass('z-item-current');
    $items.each(function(index) {
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.data('z-item-index', index);
        if(index === current) {
            $self.addClass('z-item-current z-item-show');
            var pre = current - 1,
                next = current + 1;
            pre = pre < 0 ? count - 1 : pre;
            next = next > count - 1 ? 0 : next;
            $($items[pre]).addClass('z-item-previous z-item-show');
            $($items[next]).addClass('z-item-next z-item-show');
        }
    });
    // reselect or filter $items
    // if has z-item-show class, show it; otherwise, hide it.
};
```

As code above shows, I want to reselect/filter a jQuery object. To be specific, I want to split `$items` to `$items with z-item-show class` and `$items without z-item-show class`.

Currently, `$items.each` is an approach, and `$items.parent().find` is another.

Any other approach(more elegant)?

Comment: Just a side-note: `$($items[pre])` could be better achieved using `eq()`: `$items.eq(pre)`

Comment: @George yes, more elegant.

Comment: Can you put together a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? I assume your problem is resetting the previous/next for the previously selected item. You should be able to track `current` and show/hide the individual item based on the next and previous values for that, similar to what you are doing for the new selection.

Comment: @Rhumborl what you assume is right. I want to handle the `previous/current/next` item specially and just hide other items. But to the question I aksed, no need to provide *jsfiddle*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-selector) and [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/#not-selector) to grab the items with the class or not:

```
$items.filter('.z-item-show').show();
$items.not('.z-item-show').hide();
```

This is cleaner than `$items.each()`, but will probably be less efficient, as it does 2 loops.

Comment: It works, but as you said, not that efficient. So waiting for a better answer( if it exists).

Answer (score 0):

As you want to just handle the manipulate the existing and new previous/next/current items, you can handle it all in your existing `each` function. Just check its position relative to the current index and add and remove classes as appropriate:

```
function initItems($items, current, count) {
    $items.each(function(index) {

        var $self = $(this);
        $self.data('z-item-index', index);

        if(index === current) {
            // current item
            $self.addClass('z-item-current z-item-show')
                .removeClass('z-item-next z-item-previous');
        }
        else if(index === (current == 0 ? count - 1 : current - 1)) {
            // previous item
            $self.addClass('z-item-previous z-item-show')
                .removeClass('z-item-next z-item-current');
        }
        else if(index === (current == count - 1 ? 0 : current + 1)) {
            // next item
            $self.addClass('z-item-next z-item-show')
                .removeClass('z-item-current z-item-previous');
        }
        else {
            // none of the above - remove all classes
            $self.removeClass('z-item-next z-item-previous z-item-current z-item-show');
        }
    });
};
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhumborl/4m8ep4f4/)